# Another term for "FYI"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms, abbreviations

I am writing a description for one of our internal repositories of knowledge we have at my company, and I want to describe one of them as being "a hub of FYIs to keep all teams up to date on the latest news, alerts, etc."

I was wondering if there's a better noun other than "FYI" to describe nuggets of information that isn't necessarily urgent, but is there for reference? I tried to replace "FYI" with "information", "knowledge", but it doesn't quite have that implication that these are short, and are just there for other people's reference.

Thank you!

Comment: I thought this was what FAQ was for?

Comment: "FYI, ..." may be replaced by "As a sidenote, ,...". Then, consider "*SideNotes*".

Comment: Reference notes.  Scrap "hub."  Collection would work.

Answer (score 2):

How about "factoid"? It's a term often used as:

- a brief or trivial item of news or information.

Purists will argue that it can also mean:

- an assumption or speculation that is reported and repeated so    often that it becomes       accepted as fact.

Answer (score 0):

**Notifications** or *notices* are generally used to provide exactly what you describe (the latest news, alerts, etc.)

> an official announcement about something that has happened or will happen ([MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/notification))

You may have your computer or some applications (email, for example) set up to provide *notifications* accessible through a notification panel or bar. It may even provide a short-lived pop-up that has the tone of "FYI" that you are looking for:

[image]

Also, **announcements**

> a public or official statement that gives people information about something ([MacMillan #1](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/announcement?q=announcements))

Here are some web pages that show *announcements* being used exactly this way for organizing their latest news:

- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/announcements/)
- [Trader Joes](http://traderjoes.com/announcements)
- [Internal Revenue Service](https://www.irs.gov/tax-exempt-bonds/announcements)

Comment: Excellent suggestions, although I find the words "Notification" and "Announcement" to be more active than a passive "FYI" suggests. "Notice" is a little closer, "hub of notices" or "hub of notices and FYIs" may work.

Comment: You may consider *announcements* to be little more casual than *notifications*, then. Things people may or may not find of immediate interest or importance (birthdays, weddings, awards, "in case you're interested"). These might be considered just things that are happening in the background, but don't have any immediate effect on regular activities.

Answer (score 0):

Nota bene: N.B. This is a very useful little tool and takes up little space. FYI, if really for memos or emails but it is not formal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene

Comment: Nota bene (from Latin) means "note carefully", in other words, it's a warning, and it is formal, as many latin phrases are. For example: "N.B. Any papers turned in after their due date will receive a grade of ZERO." It's a pretty far cry from FYI.

Comment: @medica fyi in the OP's context was incorrect. fyi is  used in memos and suchlike. Nota bene is not just a warning. Perhaps N.B. wouldn't work here in the flow of a sentence. It could be under a graph: N. B. This data is still being collected. I can think of multiple ways in which it is used to add additional information to some information as an additional piece of information.

Answer (score -1):

JSYK: [Just so you know](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=JSYK): (Body of answer must be at least 30 characters. I only had 24.)

Comment: It's very easy to overcome the 30 character limit. Cite the source, Urban Dictionary, include an example, and say whether this acronym is commonly understood.